# How do I setup curl / wget with FTP proxy?

Tags: unix, ftp, proxy, wget, curl

I'm having a good deal of trouble getting curl or wget to download files from FTP servers through an FTP proxy.  I have setup GUI FTP programs to work...

[gFTP](http://www.gftp.org/) works with these settings:

[image]

I get output like below when just using curl/wget with the ftp_proxy variable set to the proxy hostname:

```
# curl -v ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.05.tar.gz
* About to connect() to proxy blah port 21 (#0)
*   Trying blah... connected
* Connected to blah (blah) port 21 (#0)
> GET ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.05.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.0 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8h zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.10
> Host: ftp.astron.com:21
> Pragma: no-cache
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
220-
220-Enter an Internet ftp address at the Name prompt.
220 Type help for usage information.
500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
```

Is there some way I can configure the shell environment and/or curl/wget with the same settings as gFTP for passing through an FTP proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the type of proxy used.

The proxy you are using is an FTP proxy.  Wget`and Curl both use HTTP proxies.

Comment: Both curl and wget support FTP proxies...
wget: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Proxies ...
curl: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

Comment: Ah no - they support proxies for FTP transfers using HTTP proxies - not FTP native proxies.  The protocols are different.  The "GET ftp://blah.blah HTTP/1.1" in your debug output is a dead giveaway - that's an HTTP proxy request that is being generated.

Comment: Hmm, okay.  Are there any command line tools which DO support native FTP proxying?

Comment: You may not need them - the way the FTP proxy works you may be able to slip the details into the URL...  f t p://ftp@remote.host.com@ftp.proxy.com/path/to/file without any proxy set might possibly work.  It's worth a try anyway

Comment: If that doesn't work, try missing out the ftp@ or maybe changing the first @ to %40

Comment: Aha!  Victory, thank you.  That's stupidly painful, but here's my regex for reworking the URLs: perl -pe 's/(ftp\:\/\/)(\S+?)\/(\S+)$/$1ftp%40$2\@proxy.blah.com\/$3/'

Comment: For further reference, the "Types of firewalls" list here is useful: http://linuxnet.ch/groups/linuxnet/wiki/a6fa7/FTP_via_Proxy.html

Comment: Also, I found there is a feature request filed for wget to support FTP proxy auth: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?21439

Comment: curl is usable with ftp proxy as per the curl manual. The following command worked for me with pure ftp server with a ftp proxy in between. `curl  -u "anonymous@myftp.server.com :anonymous" ftp://myproxy:21/path/to/server-ftp-file`

Comment: Extract from the manual:  
Most FTP proxy servers are set up to appear as a normal FTP server from the client's perspective, with special commands to select the remote FTP server.
 curl supports the -u, -Q and --ftp-account options that can be used to set up transfers through many FTP proxies. For example, a file can be uploaded to a remote FTP server using a Blue Coat FTP proxy with the options: 
`curl -u "Remote-FTP-Username@remote.ftp.server Proxy-Username:Remote-Pass"     --ftp-account Proxy-Password --upload-file local-file     ftp://my-ftp.proxy.server:21/remote/upload/path`

Comment: Using other options of curl I was still seeing the GET ... HTTP 1.1 in the verbose output. Even forcing curl with --proto="=ftp" didn't work. But the above command did. Hope this helps someone else.